# Executing custom sql including complex select joins using entity framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My application currently uses ado.net to access the database.

It allows users to configure dashboards by passing custom sql. The custom sql includes joins on multiple tables and the columns of every table are included in the result.

We are migrating from ado.net to entity framework 4.

How do I execute the same queries using entity framework?

Also other code in the application requires firing custom complex join queries on the database. This is done by developers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use inline queries and even stored procedue in entityframework

see example for query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738451

see example for stored procedure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx

Comment: My end user has entered database queries that i need to fire. The first link provided requires passing linq sql queries. The moment i pass a database join query it gives me scope or context error.

Comment: My Database tables are USER(primary table) and USER_DETAILS(child table) related by USER_ID.

Comment: The initial database query : "SELECT u.USER_ID, u.LOGIN_ID, u.FIRST_NAME, u.LAST_NAME, u.GENDER, ud.USER_ITEM_ID, ud.ITEM_VALUE from [USER] u LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS ud ON u.USER_ID = ud.USER_ID ".
The entity framework query to which I had to change to : "SELECT u.USER_ID, u.LOGIN_ID, u.FIRST_NAME, u.LAST_NAME, u.GENDER, ud.USER_ITEM_ID, ud.ITEM_VALUE from USERs as u LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS as ud ON u.USER_ID = ud.USER_ID ".
I need to be able to fire my database queries using Entity Framework. I have no ides how many columns these queries would return or the datatype of these columns.

Comment: I'm sorry for the untidy look of the reply. I had formatted the reply, but I don't know how the formatting dissappeared.

Comment: @ChrisSerrao: Don't pass code to comments. If your question doesn't provide necessary details, update the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic queries you cannot execute them through EF. EF works in strongly typed manner so it expects that you created the type with correct properties (with correct types) at design time (you can create the type at runtime as well but it requires you to create dynamic assembly, emit IL, etc.).

Use your old approach for this type of queries.